# Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm getting the following error. What is wrong?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined
```

Code:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit(Object.fromEntries(new FormData($event.target)))" wire:ref="send-message">
   <input type="text" name="message" wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:target="send-message">
   <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

This is inside a `<x-livewire-modal>` component if that matters.

Comment: I think you have to remove the dollar sign.

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#action-parameters - no - based on the docs you should be able to access it via a $ sign (see Magic Actions)

Comment: use ```wire:submit``` instead of ```wire:submit.prevent```

Comment: @ikhvjs That gives me the same error message and a full page load, which I don't want. Thank you!

Comment: @SeaBass, ```wire:submit.prevent="true"``` also add one more line ```wire:submit=xxxx```

Comment: @ikhvjs That gave me same error message in the console as well as this: `Unable to call component method. Public method [true] not found on component: `

Comment: Out of curious, if you do ```wire:submit.prevent="console.log($event.target)"```, does it work for you? Or you try to just do ```wire:submit.prevent="submit($event.target)"```, you abstract all the logic in the submit function instead.

Comment: @ikhvjs Noep, doesn't work either. Something is fishy here `Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined`

Comment: @SeaBass, I suddenly have an idea, but I am not sure. If you changed to ```wire:submit.prevent="submit"``` and inside your submit function, you can get a event object. such as ```function submit(event){}``` like js ?

Comment: @ikhvjs `submit` is a method in my php class via livewire, so not sure how I would do that?